# Adding a Small Note to Posts That I Favorite

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I have a lot of posts that I've currently favorited.  Currently, I have to comb through them and figure out why I favorited them. Was it because I wanted to post an answer later and I didn't have time? Did I just want to be able to quickly find the post later for reference?

I think it would add a lot of value to the favorites feature if there was an option to add a small note as to why it was favorited.  Thinking in terms of saving Stackoverflow's database space, a more pragmatic approach might be to add a tagging system that works like the post tagging system (has community-curated options), such as:

- `reference later`
- `answer later`
- `interesting for research`

.... etc.

Do other Stackoverflow-ers think this could be a useful idea?

Comment: I'm sure you could create a userscript for this, I'm not sure what benefit there would be to store it on the SO database.

Comment: One thing I was thinking of was when I'm trying to answer someone's questions on my phone or tablet.  It would be really cool to look up references on my phone that I favorited on my laptop.  Also, my phone is where I see a lot of questions and don't have time to answer and want to save for later when I'm on my laptop.

Comment: Not sure about "community curated options". One persons "answer later" would clash with another persons "I've already answered it". But I quite like the idea of adding private notes to why I made something a favourite.

Comment: OK, I upvoted this.  Unfortunately, I only did so after asking almost the exact same thing and getting dupe comments.  I did search first, honest!

Comment: Oh - I starred this post, but I'll probably lose it...

Comment: This suggestion should be implemented. Today I found a post that had a an excellent piece of information on the **8th** answer. Not a chance am I going to remember why I favourited this in a couple months time.

Answer (score 6):

I use Microsoft Edge and OneNote for this, but then again, I may be a teeny weeny bit biased.

[image]

I guess my point is that there are numerous ways to do this on the client-side already, some of which sync as well (even if you're vehemently against Microsoft and don't use OneNote, there's the equally ubiquitous Evernote), and it just sounds too gimmicky and too "personal" (i.e. only ever seen by the user annotating their favorites) to be of much value to the site. There is already a favorites feature. It doesn't need to become a full-blown module all on its own.

In fact, I keep my drafts in OneNote as well since on-site drafts are transient and extremely limited (AFAIK you can only keep one draft of *any* type of post at any given time, and only for a short period of time). But I see why drafts would be much more useful in a pinch, even despite their short-livedness.

Comment: +1 for using *cutting* Edge technology...

Comment: @rene *groan*...

Comment: I used to use OneNote and Evernote too, until I realized that I never actually go back and look at my notes `:P` [Having over 3,000 favorited questions probably doesn't help](http://stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake?tab=favorites)...

Comment: @Cupcake Why, just why??

Comment: @bluefeet: I'm not all that much better, [close to a thousand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=favorites)...

Comment: @bluefeet I don't remember, I stopped taking notes `:P`

Comment: Edge doesn't support Adblock plus; that's a deal-breaker for me.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you ask but may be of help to find or sort things out.

Last year I had a similar feature-idea, and while playing with Isotope made an interface to filter any user favorites by tags and by answers, score, views or activity (pulling info from the API). It uses the browser `localStorage` to keep track of each user on each site (main or meta).

Seems to be working but maybe there are some bugs left behind, haven't touched it since (just minor adjustments right now). I'm seeing now that no feedback is given about the API request/response; only an issue if user has too many favs. Feel free to fork or grab any code you find useful; individual notes would be a great add-on.

<kbd>[Live web app](https://brasofilo.github.io/stack.favs/)</kbd> + <kbd>[Source code](https://github.com/brasofilo/stack.favs/tree/gh-pages)</kbd>
<sup><sub>(web app under quota limitations, 10k/day, if 120 users pull Bolt Clock's favorites it's gone :)</sub></sup>

<kbd>[image: SE favorites]</kbd>