# Follow-up reminder option for posts

Tags: feature-request

Very rarely, I run into a situation where Stack Overflow essentially says to me "can't do that now, come back later".

For example, I've already close-voted on a post, and wish to take advantage of my opportunity to vote again after the required time has passed (e.g. because the close votes were invalidated by a bounty, without any actual improvement to the question). Or I would like to check in on a post after a day or two, but haven't commented on a post or am worried a comment notification will go to someone else instead of me. That sort of thing.

Right now, the only thing I can do (as far as I know) is toggle the "Favorite" on the post. But for me, that's not really the right tool. I mostly use the Favorites to track questions I find particularly useful, often because they are canonical for oft-repeated duplicates. It doesn't conveniently track posts in a way that makes it simple for me to review the Favorites and find the ones I want to follow-up on now.

So here's my feature request:

> I would like to be able to click a button and have a calendar control appear, from which I can select a date on which I'd like for Stack Overflow to remind me via the usual "inbox" notification that I'd intended to review that post.
>
> Ideally, this feature would be present for each post on a page, whether question or answer. But it would be sufficiently useful if it was only for the question itself, as is the case for the "Favorite" toggle now.

Comment: +1. there have been moments when I came across a question or answer where I felt obliged to upvote but I could not because I had already run out my quota for the day. Keeping manual track of those questions to do it later is pretty arduous and can potentially hinder upvote on deserving post.

Comment: @pnuts: actually, the daily vote limit wasn't what I meant. I've edited the question to clarify

Comment: Previous requests like this have always been dismissed by noting that your browser is already very good at book-marking URLs.  Try it.

Comment: @HansPassant: sorry, I don't get your meaning. What book-marking feature in my browser causes the browser to notify me in e.g. 14 days to go visit the link? Please explain.

Comment: @pnuts: yes, especially if "I may want to return to the post for a moderation activity I don’t immediately have time for" is extended to include my scenario (i.e. I have time for it, it's just not a available activity at the moment).

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307188/adding-a-small-note-to-posts-that-i-favorite

Comment: Actually, I've been wishing for exactly this feature, for the same reasons. It would be a useful moderator tool IMO.

Comment: This could probably be implemented as a userscript, assuming you aren't clearing localstorage when you close your browser, or through a 3rd party such as google calendar, or possibly even trello.

Comment: @KevinB: it's definitely implementable using a third-party calendar/reminder tool; I don't know anything about Stack Overflow "userscripts", but grant it may be possible with that too. But that's not in and of itself a reason to reject the proposal. My feeling is that this would be a feature that is useful in a way that is fundamental to the purpose and capabilities of Stack Overflow and so is appropriate as a built-in feature, even if it can be implemented other ways by users on a user-by-user basis. Why make each user re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If it could be implemented as a userscript, we could potentially get a handle on how many people are interested in actually using it, rather than simply seeing how many people like the idea. I for example like the idea, but in practice would never actually use it.

Comment: @Kevin _"in practice would never actually use it"_ -- a relevant point, but not one that carries much weight, I'd say. At best, userscripts are not discoverable for the average user, and at worst incomprehensible to some. Implementing a feature as a userscript is a good prototyping measure, but it's not clear to me it's a good way of evaluating popularity of a feature. In any case, I don't think popularity is the top consideration for all features; there are a number of built-in features I and most other users likely will _never_ use. But they exist, and others do find them useful (I presume).

Comment: This would be good for a wide variety of tasks. For example, if one provided some guidance to a new user regarding a misguided question and wished to stop by to see if it had been improved later, for a moderator following up on a possible spammer, for a question about software for which a new version will imminently be released and may resolve the issue... I can imagine many uses for this.

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea, I wrote a userscript to test it out and honestly I have used it every day since I started. I've had an answer typed up for over a week but haven't posted as the [code is still being reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114586/stack-exchange-post-reminder) on Code Review. It adds a calendar icon in the vote cell of each post which activates a date picker and then displays notifications in the navbar consistent with other notifications. It still needs some work though.

Comment: All of my Yes. I hate having to set a reminder on my phone/pinning the tab in Chrome/adding a bookmark so I don't forget to act on something later (e.g. awarding a bounty). I know there's an e-mail notification but when I'm awarding and existing answer I want to award it as soon as the 24-hour grace period ends so others won't be disappointed when they see it featured and come to answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a fantastic idea and I believe implementing it would be a great addition to the site.

I decided to implement this as a userscript to see how things would work out and honestly, I've used it every day.

This could be especially helpful for moderators, being able to *set and forget* reminders for questions or answers that I want to come back to has been pretty useful for me.

---

#### The UserScript

It supports questions and answers and *should* work on all StackExchange sites and their meta sites.

The script adds a calendar icon in each vote cell which activates a date picker where you can select any future date for your reminder.

[image: post reminder screenshot]

Reminders are displayed at the top of the screen in the navbar alongside your inbox/achievements and can be dismissed by clicking on them.

Notifications include

- Post Title (*at the time of setting the reminder - this may change due to edits*)
- Post Type (*question or answer*)
- Reminder Date
- Site Name

[image: post reminder notification list]

The script is designed to work with Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey as these are the script managers that support GM_* functions which is used to keep track of the reminders. It should be noted that notifications are only synchronized between tabs with Tampermonkey due to limited GM_addValueChangeListener support.

The source is posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114586/stack-exchange-post-reminder) (*<s>with an open +100 bounty</s>*) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/enki-code/UserScripts/blob/master/post-reminder.user.js), feel free to dig through it, fork it, change whatever you want.

Now, as others have mentioned, a userscript really isn't the right answer here, I just wanted to prototype something to get a visual idea of how things would look and work.

Hopefully the screenshots will add a bit more detail to your feature-request as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Click an icon to shoved the answer into a "rewind queue".**

Then after we finish the project (or obtain a working solution), we can go back and up-vote/comment on all the crap that actually worked for us.

This will lead to:

- More precise comments
- Accurate up-voting (regretting a previous upvote)
- Rather than a reviewer having to jump into a question "cold" and edit or merge duplicates, a person who is already warmed to the subject will be ready to tidy things up.

**Because:**

How many times have I implemented 2 or 3 top answers, but never up-voted either because I had to test all solutions to see which one actually worked best.

Don't we all poke around at a couple similar pages containing relevant hints at a possible solution -- never getting nor attempting to back-track to up-vote all the posts that helped us achieve a solution.

So the idea would be to have some kind of icon ("rewind"?) that we can click and post/answer will get shoved into a list. Then 3 days later we're prompted to review all the items we pushed into the rewind queue.

**Colored Flags?**

We might use a flag icon that can have multiple colors, where each color will be related to a concept, so we can group ideas under the same color.