# Mark question to add it to a "to answer" list

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There have been certain times where I was working on SO via a mobile device and saw questions I could answer, but needed some other resources (not available on my mobile device). Not wanting to just leave a comment or upvoting, I wouldn't have any reference anymore to find this question.

How else would it be possible to find this question again?

I would like to have an option similar to flagging, but more like something you want to find again easily. It is to create some sort of to-do list (a list with questions that require your attention later on)...

Comment: Why not just "favourite" it? Or bookmark it in your browser? Or leave it open in a tab?

Comment: Or even really low tech: Write the question's post ID on a piece of paper and navigate to that post later.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, "Or bookmark it in your browser? Or leave it open in a tab?" - without special sync such action wouldn't help you to find this question from other device (desktop in this case).

Comment: @Qwertiy it's not that *"special"* in this day and age... BUt OK: other, lower-tech options include sending yourself a message with the existing share link, or interacting with it in any way (if it's worth answering an upvote would probably be appropriate) so you can see it in your profile. My point is that there are many ways of achieving this without additional functionality.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to favorite it, because it isn't really a favorite question, that would require to unfavorite it afterwards. Using a google account to bookmark it would be an option (sync with all devices), but leaving open in a tab isn't, because I want to open it on another device entirely.

Comment: @davejal some browser sync tabs cross-platform, or at least allow you to see what's open (Chrome does, for example). Surely any means of marking a question would require unmarking it afterwards (unless you expect the feature built for your specific workflow, which seems a bit much...)? And what does it matter if it's not really a favourite?

Comment: You can unmark it later as "favourite". My own favourite use of the Favourite star is to mark *bad* questions, to check later on if they got improved.

Comment: I like the idea, but I think it should rather be like this: _"Add structure (tabs) to favorites"_. Then we would tab from our favourite reference posts to our favourite fun posts to our favourite to-do list posts. The current votes/activity/views structure lacks this. Granted, this would complicate things for the dev- and ux-people.

Comment: Favouriting is my go-to choice, then when I get to a PC I just got to my favorites list, click the question then click the star and add my answer.

Comment: [StackEye](http://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites) is good for the bad posts, because it'll tell you if they get changed.

Comment: @Qwertiy: sync. works on Chrome, Firefox (tabs opened on a mobile device are visible on desktop). Though I use "favorite", to answer a question later.

Comment: Personally I think a 'private note' field/area (just viewable and editable for the user) *per stackoverflow-'site'* would be a great idea, solving/aiding not only this 'problem' (and a user-script might add custom 'buttons' or actions like track good/bad/to-do url's to the 'private note', etc.). It can hold more information then just url's, doesn't require bookmarks (sync service  or change the way you use/treat favs/bookmarks) and would be available on all devices you are logged on to without hassle. However I guess/fear this ('obvious' suggestion) has been proposed (and declined) before.

Comment: Given that a task list is of only minimal use without reminders, this suggestion seems very similar to my own recent one here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311424/follow-up-reminder-option-for-posts/. It is also very similar to this related request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305448/classification-or-equivalent-option-for-favorited-questions

Comment: @davejal: 1 vote for this suggestion. I want "mark to edit" button for my own sake. Use "Favourite" button not works because I don't favourite the question. Use bookmark not works because it gets mixed with my other bookmarks. I want to see my potential-to-answer list of questions when I open my stackoverflow app and then can answer them from there.