# Why would I favorite my own post?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, bookmarks

I saw every new user favorite his own question even I have favorited my own posts in past. I don't understand the motive behind this. Moreover, my vote will also be counted for badges related to favorite.

Is it allowed *intentionally* ? What are the advantages I will get if I favorite my own post ?

Comment: I think new users just don't know they can navigate back to their own questions from their profile, and the star icon for favoriting makes it seem vaguely like bookmarking the page in their browser.

Comment: What are the advantages of not allowing one to favourite their own question? One disadvantage is that it complicates the software that the site operates on - for no good reason.

Comment: IMO: the people you're talking about favorite their question because it is their favorite (and only) question.

Comment: @Oded I recall the the favorite star is like a vote on the database; it seems simple to reuse the same checks for up/down voting their own posts for the favorite vote.

Comment: @Braiam - to what end? Not allowing to up/down vote on your own post has a purpose. What is the purpose of not allowing one to favorite their own post?

Comment: @Oded you say that a disadvantage would be "complicates the software that the site operates on", and I believe that that wouldn't be so. Setting facts straight can prevent problems down the road.

Comment: If one person asks a lot of question and want to look up some of them frequently marking it as favorite helps. And there is no disadvantage in making own question favorite.

Comment: I find that a common issue is that new users favourite their posts to give the impression that people 'like' the question. Maybe disallow it 'til a certain reputation level?

Comment: Sometimes if you ask a lot of questions you want to be able to find some out of the stack, some users have 100s of questions

Comment: "even I have favorited my own posts in past" - and you're asking *us* why you'd do that?

Comment: Tangentially related: does a user marking their question as a 'favorite' question affect whether it will show up in the low-quality review queue?

Comment: like a bookmark. if the answers are very useful and if you wish to read it later for reference then you can mark it as favorite. but by reading all the posts here I assume its not the intended purpose.

Comment: What do you mean you "saw every new user favorite his own question"? I'm pretty sure a lot of new users *don't* favorite their own question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One useful feature of marking your own question as favorite is the activity indicator that is shown in your profile tab:

[image: favorite activity indicator]

That would relieve you from running a search like

> [user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a1997093%20is%3aq%20)

, watch the [question tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997093?tab=questions&sort=activity) or [answer tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997093?tab=answers&sort=activity) and remembering when the last top modified time was when they checked earlier.

Comment: Another way to do this without favoriting is ordering by "activity" on the answers/questions tab, but I presume you already know about that, no?

Comment: @Braiam fair enough, added...

Comment: I'd be surprised if *new users* even knew about this. But it's a reasonable answer to a question that is being consciously asked by a 10k user.

Answer (score 15):

One possible advantage that you would get is that if the question is subsequently deleted it still shows up in the favourites tab for 10K users with a reddish background colour.

[image]

Deleted questions are not by default shown on user profiles, and even when they are shown it is restricted to ones posted by the current user and [within the last 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/145673).

Comment: Huh, didn't know that. Excellent!

Answer (score 5):

> Why would I favorite my own post?

For the same reason that you'd favourite *any* question: to add it into a shortlist of questions that you wish to be able to easily find again in the future.

> I saw every new user favorite his own question

This is dishonest at best. It is clear that not "every new user" does this.

I do see it from time to time, and I believe it is a combination of:

- not researching how the site works, and clicking on buttons randomly;
- not knowing there's a list of your previous questions as well as your favourites;
- trying to make the question look more popular than it is.

> even I have favorited my own posts in past

Then perhaps you should be the one to tell *us* why this occurs.

> Is it allowed intentionally ?

I don't see any compelling reason that this feature should work any differently just because you happened to write the question.

Answer (score -7):

I tend to add questions that I have answered or commented upon recently to my favourites. My reason is to have a quick way of seeing which of them have recently been updated, because I am interested in the progress of that question. Occasionally, less than weekly, I purge several question from my favourites because they have had no activity and also because I have forgotten why I was interested in the question. This latter is why I liked [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307188/adding-a-small-note-to-posts-that-i-favorite) about being able to add a private comment to when I add a favourite.

Comment: I think this question is about users favoriting their own _questions_, not answers or posts they commented on.

Comment: This question is about users favoriting their *own* questions.